# Material-UI DataGridPro save rows in state

Tags: material-ui, datagrid, state

I am trying to save the state into Redux of all rows in MUI DataGrid from this demo:
https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/#full-featured-crud-component
https://codesandbox.io/s/tiu79l?file=/demo.js
and then if the user navigates back to this DataGrid CRUD component to have all values restored at DataGrid reload.
I did not have any success using documentation available. I am not keen on Redux, I just need to understand how to persist all rows and always render the current state in DataGrid.

For example I tried to use this example:
https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/state/#restore-the-state-with-initialstate
and save in Redux the state returned by apiRef.current.exportState() and then to retrieve from Redux and pass to the initialState prop
but using redux tools I see that only columns are being saved and no rows values.

Thank you

Comment: I just played around with DataGridPro from the CRUD Demo, I did not enter a license key, not sure if that is an issue